# Is there any module to create different menus per user?

Tags: 7, routes, users

I would like to have different menus per user.

How can I achieve this?
I searched on drupal.org, but I found a module that creates a menu per role, not per user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can try [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu). It is really flexible and this means you will need some time getting the configurations right but it's really good especially when it comes to controlling menus per role.

Answer (score 0):

You can try preprocess_page function in template.php and create menus as per user retrieving menus from database.

Answer (score 0):

If it's whole menus, you may trigger them with the context module. Define a condition which relates to the user, and specify an action to display the menu's block on the proper region.